# Python code to read/write label of oscilloscope

Tags: python-3.x, instrumentation, visa, oscilloscope, pyvisa

I have written a small Python code to read back the label of a particular channel on my Tektroniks oscilloscope. The following code works well and gives the expected result.

```
import visa
rm=visa.ResourceManager()
Tek_Scope= rm.open_resource('USB0::0x0699::0x0409::C010314::INSTR')

Tek_Scope.write("CH2:LABEL?")
Readback= Tek_Scope.read()
print(Readback)
```

However, when I try to change the label of the same channel, the label name does not change. I do not get any error either. It seems I am missing any syntax to communicate and write to the instrument? In the following code, I am trying to rename my Ch1 label to VDD

```
Tek_Scope.write('CH1:LABEL %s' %'VDD' )
```

Please advise if someone has idea about this.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have Python 3. I removed the tag for Phtyon 2 just now.

Comment: can you post the write function or a minimal example demonstrating your problem?

Comment: The write() is a part of the PYVISA library i am using (I guess). Just now, I modified my code in my original issue description to reflect this. I have also added a PyVisa label now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have to quote string parameters to VISA commands:

```
Tek_Scope.write('CH1:LABEL "%s"' % 'VDD')
```

Comment: Yes this works now. Although I am wondering that when I tried the following command for some other test involving writing an float (than a string), I was able to do so without need for " " around %f     **Instrument.write(" SOURCE:VOLTAGE:LEVEL:IMMEDIATE:AMPLITUDE %f " % VDD_input)**

Comment: Well, that's a number - there's no ambiguity as to where the parameter ends, unlike a string that might contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!